# Can I break my report into groups with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have the following report:

```
var report = _repository.GetAll(
   .OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
   .Select((t, index) => new Question.Grid()
   {
      RowKey = t.RowKey,
      Row = index + 1,
      ShortTitle = t.ShortTitle
   }
```

This gives me:

```
RowKey Order  Title

0000  1  Title 1
0001  2  Title 2
0010  3  Title 3
0010  4  Title 4
0100  5  Title 5
0101  6  Title 6
0101  7  Title 7
```

What I need to do is to make a two colum report which will give me subtotals on

```
a) When digits 1-2 of the row key change
b) When digits 3-4 of the row key change
```

Like this:

```
Key   Count

00    4
0001  1
0010  3

01    3
0100  1
0101  2
```

or if this is easier:

```
Key   Count

0000  4
0001  1
0010  2

0100  2
0100  1
0101  2
```

Is this something I could do with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var groups = _repository.GetAll()
  .GroupBy(x => x.RowKey.Substring(0, 2))
  .Select(x => new 
  { 
    RowKey = x.Key, // + "00"
    Count = x.Count(),
    SubItems = x
      .GroupBy(y => y.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
      .Select(z => new 
      { 
        RowKey = z.Key, 
        Count = z.Count() 
      })
  });

foreach(var outerGroup in groups)
{
  Console.WriteLine(outerGroup.RowKey + " " + outerGroup.Count);
  foreach(var innerGroup in outerGroup.SubItems)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(innerGroup.RowKey + " " + innerGroup.Count);
  }
}
```